# Interface references

Tags: java, interface

I'm not sure how to address this question. Here is my code:

```
public interface Stuff {
    public String description();
    public double weight();
}

class Bag implements Stuff {
    public String description() {
       return "bag of";
    }
    public double weight() {
       return 10.50;
    }
}

class StuffWrapper implements Stuff {

    Stuff item;

    public StuffWrapper(Stuff item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public String description() {
        return item.description();
    }

    public double weight() {
        return item.weight();
    }
}

class Material extends StuffWrapper {

    String material;
    double weight;

    public Material(Stuff item, String material, double weight) {
        super(item);
        this.material = material;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String description() {
        return item.description() + " :" + material+ ":";
    }

    public double weight() {
        return item.weight() + weight;
    }
}
```

and then I have this:

```
Stuff icStuff = new Bag();
icStuff = new Material(icStuff, "leather", 10.30);
icStuff = new Material(icStuff, "plastic", 20.50);
System.out.println(icStuff.description() + Double.toString(icStuff.weight()));
```

which outputs

```
bag of :leather: :plastic:41.3
```

After doing all of that if I wanted icStuff to no longer reference this:

```
icStuff = new Material(icStuff, "plastic", 20.50);
```

How should I do it?

Comment: What would you like the pointer to point to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove a variable memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536854/remove-a-variable-memory)

Comment: Your `Bag` implementation makes no sense. In addition, you re-assign the `icStuff` without using it in between; this cannot possibly be what you want. Did you plan to *add* items to the bag?

Comment: I think there's some code wrongly pasted and other missing.

Comment: You want to go back to `leather` stuff? Otherwise un-referencing could be done by setting object to `null`. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Yes, I want to go back to leather stuff as if this:

    icStuff = new Material(icStuff, "plastic", 20.50);

had never happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assign it to something else, or null, or whatever you want it to reference

```
icStuff = null;
icStuff = Somethingelse;
```